# Optimizing Parameterized MySQL Queries

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I have a query that has a number of parameters which if I run from in MySQLWorkbench takes around a second to run.

If I take this query and get rid of the parameters and instead substitute the values into the query then it takes about 22 seconds to run, same as If I convert this query to a parameterized stored procedure and run it (it then takes about 22 seconds).

I've enabled profiling on MySQL and I can see a few things there. For example, it shows the number of rows examined and there's an order of difference (20,000 to 400,000) which I assume is the reason for the 20x increase in processing time.

The other difference in the profile is that the parameterized query sent from MySQLWorkbench still has the parameters in (e.g. where limit < @lim) while the sproc the values have been set (where limit < 300).

I've tried this a number of different ways, I'm using JetBrains's DataGrip (as well as MySQLWorkbench) and that works like MySQLWorkbench (sends through the @ parameters), I've tried executing the queries and the sproc from MySQLWorkbench, DataGrip, Java (JDBC) and .Net. I've also tried prepared statements in Java but I can't get anywhere near the performance of sending the 'raw' SQL to MySQL.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I don't know what it is.

The query is relatively complex, it has a CTE a couple of sub-selects and a couple of joins, but as I said it runs quickly straight from MySQL.

My main question is why the query is 20x faster in one format than another.
Does the way the query is sent to MySQL have anything to do with this (the '@' values sent through and can I replicate this in a stored procedure?

**Updated 1st Jan**

Thanks for the comments, I didn't post the query originally as I'm more interested in the general concepts around the use of variables/parameters and how I could take advantage of that (or not)

Here is the original query:

```
with tmp_bat as (select bd.MatchId,
                        bd.matchtype,
                        bd.playerid,
                        bd.teamid,
                        bd.opponentsid,
                        bd.inningsnumber,
                        bd.dismissal,
                        bd.dismissaltype,
                        bd.bowlerid,
                        bd.fielderid,
                        bd.score,
                        bd.position,
                        bd.notout,
                        bd.balls,
                        bd.minutes,
                        bd.fours,
                        bd.sixes,
                        bd.hundred,
                        bd.fifty,
                        bd.duck,
                        bd.captain,
                        bd.wicketkeeper,
                        m.hometeamid,
                        m.awayteamid,
                        m.matchdesignator,
                        m.matchtitle,
                        m.location,
                        m.tossteamid,
                        m.resultstring,
                        m.whowonid,
                        m.howmuch,
                        m.victorytype,
                        m.duration,
                        m.ballsperover,
                        m.daynight,
                        m.LocationId
                 from (select *
                       from battingdetails
                       where matchid in
                             (select id
                              from matches
                              where id in (select matchid from battingdetails)
                                and matchtype = @match_type
                             )) as bd
                          join matches m on m.id = bd.matchid
                          join extramatchdetails emd1
                               on emd1.MatchId = m.Id
                                   and emd1.TeamId = bd.TeamId
                          join extramatchdetails emd2
                               on emd2.MatchId = m.Id
                                   and emd2.TeamId = bd.TeamId
)
select players.fullname                                    name,
       teams.teams                                         team,
       ''                                                  opponents,
       players.sortnamepart,
       innings.matches,
       innings.innings,
       innings.notouts,
       innings.runs,
       HS.score                                            highestscore,
       HS.NotOut,
       CAST(TRUNCATE(innings.runs / (CAST((Innings.Innings - innings.notOuts) AS DECIMAL)),
                     2) AS DECIMAL(7, 2))                  'Avg',
       innings.hundreds,
       innings.fifties,
       innings.ducks,
       innings.fours,
       innings.sixes,
       innings.balls,
       CONCAT(grounds.CountryName, ' - ', grounds.KnownAs) Ground,
       ''                                                  Year,
       ''                                                  CountryName
from (select count(case when inningsnumber = 1 then 1 end)                           matches,
             count(case when dismissaltype != 11 and dismissaltype != 14 then 1 end) innings,
             LocationId,
             playerid,
             MatchType,
             SUM(score)                                                              runs,
             SUM(notout)                                                             notouts,
             SUM(hundred)                                                            Hundreds,
             SUM(fifty)                                                              Fifties,
             SUM(duck)                                                               Ducks,
             SUM(fours)                                                              Fours,
             SUM(sixes)                                                              Sixes,
             SUM(balls)                                                              Balls
      from tmp_bat
      group by MatchType, playerid, LocationId) as innings
         JOIN players ON players.id = innings.playerid
         join grounds on Grounds.GroundId = LocationId and grounds.MatchType = innings.MatchType
         join
     (select pt.playerid, t.matchtype, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') as teams
      from playersteams pt
               join teams t on pt.teamid = t.id
      group by pt.playerid, t.matchtype)
         as teams on teams.playerid = innings.playerid and teams.matchtype = innings.MatchType
         JOIN
     (SELECT playerid,
             LocationId,
             MAX(Score)  Score,
             MAX(NotOut) NotOut
      FROM (SELECT battingdetails.playerid,
                   battingdetails.score,
                   battingdetails.notout,
                   battingdetails.LocationId
            FROM tmp_bat as battingdetails
                     JOIN (SELECT battingdetails.playerid,
                                  battingdetails.LocationId,
                                  MAX(battingdetails.Score) AS score
                           FROM tmp_bat as battingdetails
                           GROUP BY battingdetails.playerid,
                                    battingdetails.LocationId,
                                    battingdetails.playerid) AS maxscore
                          ON battingdetails.score = maxscore.score
                              AND battingdetails.playerid = maxscore.playerid
                              AND battingdetails.LocationId = maxscore.LocationId                              ) AS internal
      GROUP BY internal.playerid, internal.LocationId) AS HS
     ON HS.playerid = innings.playerid and hs.LocationId = innings.LocationId

where innings.runs >= @runs_limit

order by runs desc, KnownAs, SortNamePart

limit 0, 300;
```

Wherever you see '@match_type' then I substitute that for a value ('t'). This query takes ~1.1 secs to run. The query with the hard coded values rather than the variables down to ~3.5 secs (see the other note below). The EXPLAIN for this query gives this:

```
1,PRIMARY,<derived7>,,ALL,,,,,219291,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
1,PRIMARY,players,,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,teams.playerid,1,100,
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,,ref,<auto_key3>,<auto_key3>,26,"teams.playerid,teams.matchtype",11,100,Using where
1,PRIMARY,grounds,,ref,GroundId,GroundId,4,innings.LocationId,1,10,Using where
1,PRIMARY,<derived8>,,ref,<auto_key0>,<auto_key0>,8,"teams.playerid,innings.LocationId",169,100,
8,DERIVED,<derived3>,,ALL,,,,,349893,100,Using temporary
8,DERIVED,<derived14>,,ref,<auto_key0>,<auto_key0>,13,"battingdetails.PlayerId,battingdetails.LocationId,battingdetails.Score",10,100,Using index
14,DERIVED,<derived3>,,ALL,,,,,349893,100,Using temporary
7,DERIVED,t,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,3323,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
7,DERIVED,pt,,ref,TeamId,TeamId,4,t.Id,65,100,
2,DERIVED,<derived3>,,ALL,,,,,349893,100,Using temporary
3,DERIVED,matches,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,114162,10,Using where
3,DERIVED,m,,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,
3,DERIVED,emd1,,ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,Using index
3,DERIVED,emd2,,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,8,"matches.Id,emd1.TeamId",1,100,Using index
3,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,"TeamId,MatchId,match_team",match_team,8,"emd1.TeamId,matches.Id",15,100,
3,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,MatchId,MatchId,4,matches.Id,31,100,Using index; FirstMatch(battingdetails)
```

and the EXPLAIN for the query with the hardcoded values looks like this:

```
1,PRIMARY,<derived8>,,ALL,,,,,20097,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
1,PRIMARY,players,,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,HS.PlayerId,1,100,
1,PRIMARY,grounds,,ref,GroundId,GroundId,4,HS.LocationId,1,100,Using where
1,PRIMARY,<derived2>,,ref,<auto_key0>,<auto_key0>,30,"HS.LocationId,HS.PlayerId,grounds.MatchType",17,100,Using where
1,PRIMARY,<derived7>,,ref,<auto_key0>,<auto_key0>,46,"HS.PlayerId,innings.MatchType",10,100,Using where
8,DERIVED,matches,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,114162,10,Using where; Using temporary
8,DERIVED,m,,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,LocationId",PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,
8,DERIVED,emd1,,ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,Using index
8,DERIVED,emd2,,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,8,"matches.Id,emd1.TeamId",1,100,Using index
8,DERIVED,<derived14>,,ref,<auto_key2>,<auto_key2>,4,m.LocationId,17,100,
8,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,"PlayerId,TeamId,Score,MatchId,match_team",MatchId,8,"matches.Id,maxscore.PlayerId",1,3.56,Using where
8,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,MatchId,MatchId,4,matches.Id,31,100,Using index; FirstMatch(battingdetails)
14,DERIVED,matches,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,114162,10,Using where; Using temporary
14,DERIVED,m,,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,
14,DERIVED,emd1,,ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,Using index
14,DERIVED,emd2,,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,8,"matches.Id,emd1.TeamId",1,100,Using index
14,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,"TeamId,MatchId,match_team",match_team,8,"emd1.TeamId,matches.Id",15,100,
14,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,MatchId,MatchId,4,matches.Id,31,100,Using index; FirstMatch(battingdetails)
7,DERIVED,t,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,3323,100,Using temporary; Using filesort
7,DERIVED,pt,,ref,TeamId,TeamId,4,t.Id,65,100,
2,DERIVED,matches,,ALL,PRIMARY,,,,114162,10,Using where; Using temporary
2,DERIVED,m,,eq_ref,PRIMARY,PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,
2,DERIVED,emd1,,ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,4,matches.Id,1,100,Using index
2,DERIVED,emd2,,eq_ref,"PRIMARY,TeamId",PRIMARY,8,"matches.Id,emd1.TeamId",1,100,Using index
2,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,"TeamId,MatchId,match_team",match_team,8,"emd1.TeamId,matches.Id",15,100,
2,DERIVED,battingdetails,,ref,MatchId,MatchId,4,matches.Id,31,100,Using index; FirstMatch(battingdetails)
```

Pointers as to ways to improve my SQL are always welcome (I'm definitely **not** a database person), but I''d still like to understand whether I can use the SQL with the variables from code and why that improves the performance by so much

***Update 2 1st Jan***

AAArrrggghhh. My machine rebooted overnight and now the queries are generally running much quicker. It's still 1 sec vs 3 secs but the 20 times slowdown does seem to have disappeared

Comment: Variables interpolated into expressions are not parameters, but both variables and parameters should act like constant values. Can you use EXPLAIN to see if there's a difference in the optimizer plan?

Comment: There could be a lot of reasons.  Show us the queries and `EXPLAINs`.  We may have suggestions on indexing or rewriting the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this is the correct answer but I thought I'd post this in case other people have the same issue.

The issue seems to be the use of CTEs in a stored procedure. I have a query that creates a CTE and then uses that CTE 8 times. If I run this query using interpolated variables it takes about 0.8 sec, if I turn it into a stored procedure and use the stored procedure parameters then it takes about to a minute (between 45 and 63 seconds) to run!

I've found a couple of ways of fixing this, one is to use multiple temporary tables (8 in this case) as MySQL cannot re-use a temp table in a query. This gets the query time right down but just doesn't fell like a maintainable or scalable solution. The other fix is to leave the variables in place and assign them from the stored procedure parameters, this also has no real performance issues. So my sproc looks like this:

```
create procedure bowling_individual_career_records_by_year_for_team_vs_opponent(IN team_id INT,
                                                                                IN opponents_id INT)
begin

    set @team_id = team_id;
    set @opponents_id = opponents_id;

    # use these variables in the SQL below

    ...


end
```

Not sure this is the best solution but it works for me and keeps the structure of the SQL the same as it was previously.

Answer (score 0):

In your WITH construct, are you overthinking your select in ( select in ( select in ))) ... overstating what could just be simplified to the `with Innings` I have in my solution.

Also, you were joining to the extraMatchDetails TWICE, but joined on the same conditions on match and team, but never utliized either of those tables in the "WITH CTE" rendering that component useless, doesn't it?  However, the MATCH table has homeTeamID and AwayTeamID which is what I THINK your actual intent was

Also, your WITH CTE is pulling many columns not needed or used in subsequent return such as Captain, WicketKeeper.

So, I have restructured... pre-query the batting details once up front and summarized, then you should be able to join off that.

Hopefully this MIGHT be a better fit, function and performance for your needs.

```
with innings as 
(
select
        bd.matchId,
        bd.matchtype,
        bd.playerid,
        m.locationId,
        count(case when bd.inningsnumber = 1 then 1 end) matches,
        count(case when bd.dismissaltype in ( 11, 14 ) then 0 else 1 end) innings,
        SUM(bd.score) runs,
        SUM(bd.notout) notouts,
        SUM(bd.hundred) Hundreds,
        SUM(bd.fifty) Fifties,
        SUM(bd.duck) Ducks,
        SUM(bd.fours) Fours,
        SUM(bd.sixes) Sixes,
        SUM(bd.balls) Balls
    from
        battingDetails bd
            join Match m
                on bd.MatchID = m.MatchID           
    where
        matchtype = @match_type
    group by 
        bd.matchId,
        bd.matchType, 
        bd.playerid,
        m.locationId
)


select
        p.fullname playerFullName,
        p.sortnamepart,
        CONCAT(g.CountryName, ' - ', g.KnownAs) Ground,
        t.team,
        i.matches,
        i.innings,
        i.runs,
        i.notouts,
        i.hundreds,
        i.fifties,
        i.ducks,
        i.fours,
        i.sixes,
        i.balls,
        CAST( TRUNCATE( i.runs / (CAST((i.Innings - i.notOuts) AS DECIMAL)), 2) AS DECIMAL(7, 2)) 'Avg',
        hs.maxScore,
        hs.maxNotOut,
        '' opponents,
        '' Year,
        '' CountryName
    from
        innings i
            JOIN players p
                ON i.playerid = p.id 
            join grounds g
                on i.locationId = g.GroundId 
                and i.matchType = g.matchType
            join
            (select 
                    pt.playerid, 
                    t.matchtype, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ', ') team
                from 
                    playersteams pt
                        join teams t 
                            on pt.teamid = t.id
                group by 
                    pt.playerid, 
                    t.matchtype) as t 
                on i.playerid  = t.playerid 
                and i.MatchType = t.matchtype 
            join
                ( select
                        i2.playerid,
                        i2.locationid,
                        max( i2.score ) maxScore,
                        max( i2.notOut ) maxNotOut
                    from
                        innings i2
                    group by
                        i2.playerid,
                        i2.LocationId ) HS
                on i.playerid = HS.playerid
                AND i.locationid = HS.locationid
            FROM 

    where 
        i.runs >= @runs_limit
    order by 
        i.runs desc, 
        g.KnownAs, 
        p.SortNamePart
    limit 
        0, 300;
```

Now, I know that you stated that after the server reboot, performance is better, but really, what you DO have appears to really have overbloated queries.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.

I'll go back and examine the WITH construct again and see if what you suggest works.

I need the two emds, this is not the full query and the use of those joined tables isn't shown here

The CTE is pulling in too many columns, I'm being lazy as the CTE is used in many other queries.  I wanted to simply re-use rather than have to work out the columns each time

The queries are complex  but at least some of that is needed, for example the HS subquery can't simply get MAX(score), MAX(notout), it has to get the max value of 'notout' for a given value of the score

Comment: @KevinJones, ok on extra columns, but your query should put all that you expect.  The joins you had were duplicating the join to same context of team, not the Home vs Away team.  Provide the entire query and I can try to offer editing extra, but take into consideration.